# how to use the bounce effect in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have included the plugin and written code like

```
if(page) { $.post(page,{},function(data){callBackFunction(data)}); }

function callBackFunction(data)
{

$('.page_change').html(data);
$('.page_change').effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
$('#submit_show').show();
}
```

The data change is happening but the bouce effect i am not getting..how do i solve this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.effect() is in jQuery UI.  Are you including the jQuery UI file?

Comment: yeah included all of them..whole package.

Comment: @pradeep: what package is that?